# Button with picture and text inside

Tags: sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1, sencha-touch-2.2

I want to know, how to create a button that looks like this: (everything inside the gray container is a button)

How can I put picture and text inside button? XTemplate? CSS in text property?

Thank you!

Sencha Touch 2

[image]

Solution:

```
{
    xtype: 'button',
    html: '<img style="margin-left: 35px;" src="http://www.timwickstrom.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/beer1.png" width="200" height="200" /><br /><span style="your style">Beer</span>',
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use [html config](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.0/#!/api/Ext.Button-cfg-html):

```
xtype: 'button',
html: '<img src="your image source"/> width="" height=""'
text: '50$'
```

Comment: I could kiss you right now but that would be gay! XD Thank you! BTW. text property doesn't work when I have HTML property. In my question I will put my solution.